# Excellent app for OSM browsing on smartphone

Tags: openstreetmap, android

I am looking for a decent app to browse OpenStreetMap on my Android smartphone in the offline mode. I have already bought [OsmAnd+](http://osmand.net/) and the Skobbler's [OSM Navigation and Maps](http://www.skobbler.com/apps), and while their UIs are exactly at the opposite ends of the scale, neither offers some simple and important functionality.

OSM Navigation and Maps interface is beautiful (a map is a visual thing, so eye-pleasing is paramount for efficient use) and simple in comparison to what OsmAnd+ does. It makes the maps fast to render. Navigation is good. What is lacking dramatically is all the additional data present in OSM (POIs).

OsmAnd+ knows a lot more, but creates screens like this: [image]

Each tiny street is drawn with two lines, and all remote shops and train stations are marked. At the same time, getting the information from the program is almost impossible. The street names are shown randomly. I cannot click a street and get information about it. I cannot ask the program to hide most of the things and keep just what I want.

So my question is: is an app I am searching for available? I want to be able to

- see only relevant information (aka layers)
- click an object to see its data

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a call for app recommendations.

Comment: I use Mapfactor https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapfactor.navigator&hl=en osm data and offline mode with navigation, is as good as the data has car mode (big buttons) etc.

Comment: Also check this out https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android